# Navigation controller affecting app overall background image

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have an application where when it begins, it loads a viewController which loads the Default.png launch image and holds it there for 1.5 seconds, then that image fades out, then fades into another image which will be the background image for my entire application. From here it loads the first viewController and then the buttons and navigation bar fade in.

So it goes SplashScreeVC - Default.png presented 
Default.png Fades out
New Image fades in (This is the apps overall background image)
Loads MainVC with buttons and nav bar alpha set to 0.1.
Method called to fade in the nav bar and the buttons in the mainVC

So in my app Delegate I have this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    SplashVC *splash = [[SplashVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashView" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = splash;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

So the app loads with the Default.png, which then loads the splashVC which has the Default.png as its background image, this is shown for 1.5 seconds. I then have a some methods to fade out this image, and then fade in the image that will be used as the background image for the entire application. Then it calls the appDelegates MainNav method which loads the Navigation controller. The app Delegates MainNav method is below

```
-(void) MainNav
{
    UIViewController *main = [[MainVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];

    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:main];

    UIImage *navImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"NavBarGrey.png"];
    //Add the custom image


    [[self.navController navigationBar] setBackgroundImage:navImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    //[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xee2e24)];


    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xe7e7e7)];

    self.navController.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage.png"]];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;

}
```

The problem is when it moves from the SplashScreen VC to the MainVC, the image suddenly jerks up despite the fact it is the same image that fades in in the SplashVC.

Does anyone have any idea why this is? I am guessing it has something to do with the navigation controller affecting the image size, but not sure what to do to fix it? Do I need to create a new image for the navigation bar background with different dimensions? Or is there another way I can fix this issue?

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Edit: Fixed image jerking to the right, had image width at wrong height, but the image is still jumping up a set amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out. Seems to have to make a copy of the image and increase its height by 20 pixels and set that as the navigation bars background image. This offsets the navigation bar problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can set bacround image code like

```
yourView.setBacroundColur=[UIColour colourWithImagePttern:[UIImage ImageNamed:@""]];
```